# Using jQuery in Snap SVG load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

So I have this problem. I would like to make a page with Snap library, but I didn't find any way to select all of elements, except for the one that I am f.e. hovering over. JQuery should be good for this stuff, but I don't know how to run it in the SVG Snap load function :/ My code is:

```
<script>
var s = Snap("#svg");
Snap.load("fin.svg",onSVGLoaded);

function onSVGLoaded(d){
    var all = d.selectAll(".plasmid");
    s.append(all);
    var mono = s.select("#mono");
    mono.drag();

$(mono).click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut("slow");
    });
};
</script>
```

Where fin.svg is the external svg file, .plasmid is a class in the svg file, with all the parts of the graphics and mono is one part of the graphics. The mono.drag() part is working, but jQuery stuff is not. Can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure if jquery works with SVG, if not you may want to use jsquery svg like http://keith-wood.name/svg.html or just use the Snap click handler and animation methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
<object class="someselector" data="external.svg"></object>
```

You can use jQuery:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    var a = ($(".someselector").contents().find('svg'))[0];
    var s = Snap(a);
    var something = s.someSnapfunctions();
    });
</script>
```

For iframes and svg, always use $(windows).load and contents()

---

And you can use jQuery's functions inside $(window).load like:

```
$('.someselector').load(function(){
// do something

var b = ($(".someselector").contents().find('svg').find('anotherselector'));
b.each(function(){
    Snap($(this)[0]).attr({
         fill: "#bada55" // change color!
    });
});
```